# Problems typing in russian

Tags: languages

I'm trying to make a LaTeX file in Russian. I wrote the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Тест
\end{document}
```

But i got [error](http://pastebin.com/GdPM8eFf)
Im had tried install some packages but it's does not affect.
(My os is mac osx)

Comment: Hi and welcome, how about using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Same problem with XeLaTex

Comment: Kicked out `inputenc` and `fontenc` and loaded `fontspec` instead?

Comment: [Error log;(](http://pastebin.com/Gf7PBpjp)

Comment: It works here using an updated full TeXlive 2014 on Linux.

Comment: `\usepackage{fontspec}`. delete the other stuff.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Тест
\end{document}
`

Comment: Did you install `cyrillic` package? http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cyrillic

Comment: Oh thx, it's works!

Comment: @Sigur, how to install packages in this form.
Im sorry for stupid questions

Comment: MacTeX has a kind of package manager but I forgot its name. Check the programs installed.

Comment: Thx.
Yes it's already installed.

Comment: There seems to be something strange in the default texlive 2014 I get `! Font T2A/cmr/m/n/12=larm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found` with the document as posted but it works if you change `[12pt]` to `10pt` which indicates an error in the map files somewhere (I think)

Comment: Note that the order of the packages should be `fontenc`, `inputenc` and `babel`, or `babel-russian` will not be able to determine the input encoding.

Answer (score 3):

The document

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Тест
\end{document}
```

compiles without any problem with MacTeX from version 2012 to 2016.

Note that `fontenc` should be loaded before `babel`.